# SAS-How to calculate the difference between max and min value?

Tags: sas

I used the following code to calculate the difference between max and min value in a  column, but it doesn't like a smart way. So could anyone give me some suggestion?

p.s. I need to put the difference back to the dataset as a new variable, because I want to delete datasets based on this difference.

```
proc univariate noprint date=test;
var time_l_;
output out=result max=max min=min;
run;

data test;
set result test;
run;

data test;
set test;
gap=max-min;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, actually, to what I'd consider a good result.  This isn't the absolute fastest way to do it, but it's probably the best when you don't need amazing performance because it's a lot less complicated than the faster methods.

Create the max/min dataset, then use `if _n_ = 1 then set result;` which will bring it in once.  The variables are automatically RETAINed, because they are brought in on the SET statement.  Then calculate the gap in the same data step.

```
proc univariate noprint data=sashelp.class;
  var age;
  output out=result max=max min=min;
run;

data test;
  if _n_=1 then set result;
  set sashelp.class;
  gap = max-min;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL solution is straightforward but leaves a message in your log regarding remerging.

```
Proc SQL;
 Create table want as
 Select *, max(age) as max_age, min(age) as min_age, calculated max_age - calculated min_age as age_diff
From have;
Quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler SQL solution using the `range` function:

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
    select *,range(age) as age_range 
    from sashelp.class;
quit;
```